# How can I stop user to open a new tab, inside link of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How can I stop user to open a new tab, inside link of iframe? User is trying to open a new link of an iframe using key combination ctrl+url. What I really want is that when user try to open a link inside an iframe, then It should opens in same tab.User should stay in the same tab.

Comment: You can't. Browsers do not allow Javascript to prevent a user opening a link in a new tab/window. Even if they did there's nothing to stop the user from copying the link and pasting it in to a new tab

Comment: You can prevent default click behaviour of anchor and use `href` attribute as current parent window (or iframe src) location. Of course, you have to get access to the iframed content, won't work for third party website iframed (same origin policy)